# Python test MySQL inserting function

Tags: python, mysql, pytest

I have a module that interacts with a MySQL database and i am currently writing tests to make sure my python code works as intended.

One of the functions i want to test takes multiple dictionaries as arguments and then performs INSERT operations on the database.

Now i would like to try to test this function.
My idea was to create an empty database locally, run the function on it and then compare the content of the database with my expectation.

However i have not found a way to easily setup and create a MySQL database purely from python without any other prerequisite. I had thought about using an sqlite db as a substitute but some of my queries have a different syntax in sqlite compared to mysql.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to set up the database "purely from Python"? What's wrong with say, starting a Docker container for the database, running your migrations and then running your tests?

Comment: @ndc85430 it just makes things way more complicated than they would have to be. at least thats what im thinking.

If sqlite3 and mysql had the same syntax then i could just to 
`mysql2 = sqlite3.connect(":mermory:");  my_cursor = mysql2.cursor()`
and i would have everything i need. I really just need not even two dozen rows in there to test what i need and i want to have it running on GitHub CI too

Comment: I don't see why that's complicated - that's pretty much the set up I have at work. I haven't used GitHub's CI system, but note that for CI systems to be quite general purpose, users typically have to run their builds in containers. I wouldn't be surprised therefore, if GitHub's CI allowed you to use Docker.

Comment: @ndc85430 do you have a resource for me to look into how do this?